# "Students writing exam" Probability question

Tags: probability

I've spent all night trying to figure out this question but I'm completely stumped.

Students A, B and C are answering a question on an exam. Students A and B have a 9/10 probability of answering the question correctly while student C has probability of 6/10 of answering correctly.

Given that the students answer the question independently, what is the probability of at least two students answering correctly?

Also, given that student C copies student A's answer, what is the probability that at least two students answer the question correctly?

At first I considered taking the probabilities of each outcome that fits the criteria ( A and B answer correctly, B and C answer correctly, A and B and C answer correctly, etc) and multiplying them together but that gives me an incorrect answer. Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: Whenever student C copies student's A answer his probability instantaneously increases to 9/10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to the first part is mostly good, but you may have overcounted - specifically, your answer must computationally distinguish at least $2$ among $3$ from *exactly* $2$ among $3$. For instance, if you just computed $A$ and $B$ answer correctly as $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$, then note that this encompasses the event $A\cap B\cap C$. What you really want is:

$$P(\text{at least two}) = P(A)P(B)P(C^{C})+P(A)P(B^{C})P(C) + P(A^{C})P(B)P(C) + P(A)P(B)P(C)$$

As a hint for the second one, note that there are only two satisfactory outcome: $A$ and $B$ must both get the answer right (all three get the correct answer), since $C$ simply copies $A$, or $A$ gets the answer right and $B$ gets the answer wrong, in which case $C$ also gets the answer right by copying $A$.

Comment: So when you multiply by the complement of each student's probability, it counts that student as getting the answer incorrect? P(A)P(B)P(C^C) for example. This is saying that A and B answer correctly and C answers incorrectly?

Comment: @Waves: exactly right. This separates the different cases where $C$ does and does not answer correctly, the latter of which is accounted for in $A\cap B\cap C$.